# Wireframe sphere with latitude/longitude OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl

I'm trying to create a wireframe sphere using openGL that has latitude and longitude lines. Currently I'm running into an issue that I think I'm simply overlooking and with a bit of help can quickly correct with creating the sphere. My code is the following inside of a class that creates displays:

```
double rho = 1;
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINE_LOOP);
for (int i = 0; i< 360; i++){
     theta = i/180 * Math.PI;
     for (int j = 0; j< 360; j++){
           double phi = j/180 * Math.PI;
           double x = rho * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
           double y = rho * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
           double z = rho * Math.sin(phi);
           gl.glVertex3d(x, y, z);
     }
     gl.glEnd();
}
```

From this code I'm currently not getting anything to display. What am I missing?

Comment: you end multiple times but begin only once, also you are using the deprecated fixed function pipeline, instead your should use the shader and buffer based 3.0 functions

Comment: I tried moving my gl.glBegin() inside the for loop, however it still doesn't create anything. That and I'm not sure what you mean by deprecated fixed function pipeline.

Comment: glBegin and glEnd are part of the deprecated part of openGL, the preferred way is to create shaders and use `glDrawArrays` and family

Comment: @ratchetfreak Have fun explaining GL 3 to a newcomer without them ragequitting entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of problems in this code:

1. As already pointed out in the comments, the `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` are unbalanced. The `glBegin()` needs to be inside the first loop.
2. The second angle should only loop from 0 to 180, not 360. This is based on the definition of spherical coordinates.
3. In the divisions `i/180` and `j/180`, both values are of type `int`, therefore the operation is an integer division. With the values used, the result of those divisions will always be 0 or 1.
4. The calculation of the z-coordinate needs to use `cos(phi)` instead of `sin(phi)`.

Not wrong, but just recommendations:

5. There's no need to use double precision values. OpenGL will use single precision anyway.
6. As mentioned in the comments, the code is using legacy features that are deprecated and deleted in modern versions of OpenGL.

Sticking with the immediate mode drawing, fixing these problems should result in working (untested) code:

```
float radius = 1.0f;
for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINE_LOOP);
    float theta = i * (Math.PI / 180.0f);
    for (int j = 0; j <= 180; j++) {
        float phi = j * (Math.PI / 180.0f);
        float x = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
        float y = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
        float z = radius * Math.cos(phi);
        gl.glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }
    gl.glEnd();
}
```

This will give you the longitude lines. The code for the latitude lines will be very similar, with the two loops swapped.

As for the discussion about deprecated/legacy features, this is somewhat broad to be covered here. So just a very quick summary:

What you're using here is typically called "immediate mode drawing". This is the way OpenGL worked in the original version. More efficient ways of specifying vertex data were introduced around 20 years ago. Initially is was Vertex Arrays, then Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO). Vertex Array Objects (VAO) were introduced later to make the state setup more efficient.

With OpenGL 3.2, which was introduced in 2009, two "profiles" were defined:

- Core Profile: Deletes the deprecated legacy features, including immediate mode drawing.
- Compatibility Profile: Still supports all features to maintain backwards compatibility.

If you write new code, particularly if you just start learning, there's no good reason to learn legacy features. The initial threshold is slightly higher when using the Core Profile (mainly because it requires you to write your own shaders in GLSL), but it's well worth it. Current versions of OpenGL ES are also much closer to the Core Profile, and do not have any of these legacy featues.

Comment: Hi Reto, thanks for the advice, I've altered my code slightly however I'm for some reason not getting my longitude lines to appear and instead am making a 2D circle with my code. Would you have any clue as to why this is occurring? I've swapped my for loops yet the image doesn't want to be in 3D